# Creating keys in a dict if it is not present

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict which would have 5 keys`['total_rows', 'rows_failed', 'dup_rows_skipped', 'total_inserts', 'total_updates']`
dict something like below-

```
    {'CO_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 0, 'dup_rows_skipped': 0, 'total_inserts': 0, 'total_updates': 1}, 
'DC_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 1}}
```

Each key ex - `CO_issuers` will have 5 keys as mentioned above . in case a key ex- `DC_issuers` doesn't have a key, it should add that key with a value as `0`.

I have gone this far , where I am looping the dict, and checking if all the keys are present or not

```
for key, value in mail_stats.items():
    if all(key in mail_stats for key in("total_rows", "rows_failed", "dup_rows_skipped", "total_inserts", "total_updates")):
```

On browsing, could find that using below code, we can do it simply, but not able to fit this is my scenario.

```
if key not in d:
    d[key] = value
```

How to do this.

Comment: Do you want to add the not found value or do you simply want the default value of 0? If is the last you can use the dictionary **get** method passing the desired default value. Ex: **dict.get('CO_issuers', 0)**

Comment: Yes. These keys would be there (CO_issuers,). the sub keys would not be present in few cases.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Could you check please. I am not sure if it is good in terms of performance

Comment: This data is from a json or json like ?

Answer (score 4):

A `defaultdict` is your best bet here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tallies = {"CO_issuers": defaultdict(int), "DC_issuers": defaultdict(int)}
```

To be clear though, this is going to work a bit differently than what you may expect.  Specifically -> the default dict instances *will not* have every key.  However, they will allow you to *retrieve* any arbitrary key. If the key does not exist, it will get the return value of the default passed in.  So `tallies['DC_issuers']['not_present']` would return `0`.

To encompass the comment, you can make it even more powerful via something like this:

```
tallies = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

With this version, every time you access `tallies` a new defaultdict that creates integers is created.  The actual tallying is done via `tallies[group][item] += 1`, and retrieving any value will return `0` if it's never been set, but return the correct value for anything present.

Comment: These keys(CO_issuers) would be dynamic. Will this work in taht case?

Comment: I am trying to get around this answer . In the meantime , I have posted an answer. Could you check please. I am not sure if it is good in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

```
mail_stats = {'CO_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 0, 'dup_rows_skipped': 0, 'total_inserts': 0, 'total_updates': 1}, 
'DC_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 1}}
```

You could iterate through each keys and check, if it is not present, update.

```
    for key, value in mail_stats.items():
        print(key, value)
        if 'dup_rows_skipped' not in value:
            value['dup_rows_skipped'] = 0
        if 'total_inserts' not in value:
            value['total_inserts'] = 0
        if 'total_updates' not in value:
            value['total_updates'] = 0

    print('Updated dict', mail_stats)
```

Updated dict-

```
 Updated dict {'CO_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 0, 'dup_rows_skipped': 0, 'total_inserts': 0, 'total_updates': 1}, 
'DC_issuers': {'total_rows': 1, 'rows_failed': 1, 'dup_rows_skipped': 0, 'total_inserts': 0, 'total_updates': 0}}
```